# Delphi SQLite3 using ZeosLib, how to share a database?

Tags: delphi, sqlite, timeout

I am using Delphi 7 and ZeosLib 6.6.6 to access SQLite3 database.

What is the best practice to use shared database.

I plan to put the database file (data.db3) in a shared location.

And the Delphi application is on local desktop computer of every users.

I want to know how to manage database locking for example. Detecting if the database is being locked by certain user, things like that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQlite3 handle database sharing by default, locally on the same computer. You have nothing to do, just open the database several times on your hard drive. Of course, it does have an overhead, and [locking will make it slower](http://www.sqlite.org/lockingv3.html) than access from one unique process.

But if by "in a shared location" you mean a network drive, as your question suggests, it probably won't work as expected.

Locking files over a network are not safe (at least in Windows world). See http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=SqliteNetwork

You should instead rely on a true Client/Server approach, still possible with SQLite3 on the server, and Clients accessing to it via the network. See e.g. our [RESTful server](http://synopse.info/fossil/wiki?name=SQLite3%20Framework) using JSON and several protocols.

Comment: My situation is a bit special, I cannot use middle-ware nor client server (I don't have permission). Me and several co-workers are doing simple data entry, and we use a shared MS-Word document :) Now, I know how to code in Delphi and I thought I would create a simple Win32 application which can be used by all users. But, I need a centralized database. I am familiar with Delphi 7 and SQLite3, but I have never made multiuser db app with it. So, placing the database in a network share is the only possible way for us.

Comment: After some thought, I think I can workaround this if I can catch the error if I cannot update the database while it is being used by someone else. Something like "waiting ..." then "retry" after couple of seconds. I know, this is not ideal, but do you think that will work?

Comment: The data entry activity itself is not intensive, probably once a day per person :)

Comment: ewlung, I give you permission to use a full database. :-)  There.

Comment: +Warren P, haha! That does not work. The issue is running "server kind" of app (e.g.: MySQL server). That, I don't have permission.

Comment: @edwlung Using such a "locking" access function could not work. You have not a security on a Windows network to have ACID write to a remote network place. Two instances may lock at once, for instance. You may fall into problems...

Answer (score 0):

1. You can put a SQLite database on a shared network resource. According to the SQLite documentation - that is not recommended. Main reason - SQLite cannot effectively manage locking on a shared resource.
2. If you need multi-user access to a SQLite database, then you may consider using middleware, like DataAbstract. As a driver for Data Abstract you can use our library AnyDAC. Some articles: [Using SQLite with AnyDAC](http://www.da-soft.com/anydac/docu/Using_SQLite_with_AnyDAC.html) and [Using Data Abstract with AnyDAC](http://www.da-soft.com/anydac/docu/Using_Data_Abstract_with_AnyDAC.html). In first article check "Connecting to SQLite database from Delphi application" for usage cases, including how to setup for concurrent access.